# UNAUTHENTICATED error when attempted to create Google Cloud Task from Java (Kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

We are attempting to create a google cloud task in our Kotlin code (same error in Java). When running locally the code works exactly as expected. Once we deploy to our DEV instance on Kubernetes, we receive the following error when attempting to create the task:

**UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential**

Our code is as follows and mimics the code provided in the [Google Docs](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#using-the-console)

The code is as follows.

```
fun createTask(filename: String?) {
        val locationId = "us-central1"
        CloudTasksClient.create().use { client ->
            val queuePath = QueueName.of(projectId, locationId, queueName).toString()

            val oidcTokenBuilder =
                OidcToken.newBuilder().setServiceAccountEmail(serviceAccount).build()

            val taskBuilder = Task.newBuilder()
                .setHttpRequest(
                    HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setBody(
                            ByteString.copyFrom(
                                filename,
                                Charset.defaultCharset()
                            )
                        )
                        .setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                        .setOidcToken(oidcTokenBuilder)
                        .setUrl(url)
                        .build()
                )
            client.createTask(queuePath, taskBuilder.build())
        }
    }
```

our service account seems to have the right credentials and we've tried just hardcoding it rather than using it as a variable but to no luck once deployed. As said before this code runs fine in our local environment using the same service account it's deployed with.

EDIT: The HttpRequest comes from the com.google.cloud.tasks.v2 library.

Comment: You are manually building the request with HTTP Headers and Body. That means you must also include the "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" yourself.

Comment: Looking into GoogleAPI implementation it appears if you pass it a OIDC token it will automatically attach that as an Authorization header. This did also work locally with no change in the code. Probably worth noting that the HttpRequest is from Google not a normal HttpRequest that would require you manually add auth headers. I'll edit and add the imports.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint and debug into your method, _does_ that generated http request have the authorization header with the bearer token?

Comment: After a bit of digging it is passing a bearer token in the request. Its using the token I believe from calling `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` although that may be the same form as the OIDC token.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting this error when trying to use an OIDC token for a service that didn't support that method of authentication. Using an OAuth token instead worked for me.

```
fun createTask(filename: String?) {
        val locationId = "us-central1"
        CloudTasksClient.create().use { client ->
            val queuePath = QueueName.of(projectId, locationId, queueName).toString()

        val tokenBuilder =
            OAuthToken.newBuilder().setServiceAccountEmail(serviceAccount).build()

        val taskBuilder = Task.newBuilder()
            .setHttpRequest(
                HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setBody(
                        ByteString.copyFrom(
                            filename,
                            Charset.defaultCharset()
                        )
                    )
                    .setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .setOAuthToken(tokenBuilder)
                    .setUrl(url)
                    .build()
            )
        client.createTask(queuePath, taskBuilder.build())
    }
}
```